# Select subtração em colunas de tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Venho tentando realizar um select que faça uma subtração de uma coluna em uma tabela, por outra coluna em uma outra tabela. Vejam na imagem abaixo o que eu preciso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por tanto, preciso somar a coluna `quantidade` da tabela `lista_geral`, enquanto os valores da coluna `cod_material` e `local` forem iguais. Em seguida, subtrair o resultado obtido pelos valores da tabela `cautela`, ou seja, enquanto os valores das colunas `cod_material` e `local`, da tabela `cautela`, forem iguais aos da tabela `lista_geral`.

O melhor resultado que consegui foi com o select abaixo:

```
SELECT cod_material, (SUM(quantidade) - (SELECT SUM(quantidade) 
FROM cautela WHERE local = 'xxx' GROUP BY cod_material)) as total_material 
FROM lista_geral WHERE local = 'xxx' GROUP BY cod_material;
```

Contudo, não obtive o resultado que preciso, pois esta subtraindo sem restringir as colunas `cod_material` e `local`.

Comment: Consegue disponibilizar o sql das tabelas bem como a massa de dados de exemplo? Assim posso tentar algo aqui no meu ambiente.

Comment: Dois subselects agregando as tabelas por cod_material , use estes selects como tabelas virtuais fazendo um join nelas , basta operar a diferença.

Comment: Você diz que quer somar por `cod_material` e `local`mas faz o GROUP BY apenas por  `cod_material`. Tnete fazer `GROUP BY  cod_material, local`.

Comment: Perguntas em que o perguntador "some", deveriam cair em um limbo, não faz sentidos destacá-las novamente em minha opinião.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer com inner join como o exemplo abaixo:

```
  SELECT c.cod_material, SUM(c.quantidade) - SUM(lg.quantidade) 
  FROM cautela c
  INNER JOIN lista_geral lg
  ON (c.cod_material = lg.cod_material and c.local = lg.local)
  group by c.cod_material;
```

Comment: A query roda, mas o resultado da errado. :/

Comment: @emersonsbr pode explicar melhor esse erro, para que eu possa tentar lhe ajudar?

Comment: Mostra a mensagem de erro que está lançando...

Answer (score 0):

Solução supondo que sempre existam dados na tabela **cautela** , senão usar *outer join*

```
select m.cod_material,(m.qtd - c.qtd) qtd
from
(SELECT cod_material, (SUM(quantidade) qtd
 FROM lista_geral 
 WHERE local = 'xxx' 
 GROUP BY cod_material) m,
(SELECT cod_material,SUM(quantidade) qtd
 FROM cautela 
 WHERE local = 'xxx' 
 GROUP BY cod_material) c
where c.cod_material = m.cod_material
```